# Mongoose findbyIdAndUpdate - how to update one field using sum from another array field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So this is how my document looks like

```
"donator": [
        {
            "_id": "5edbd7d182af1f5aceab62bb",
            "donatorName": "Niki",
            "donationValue": 5000000
        },
        {
            "_id": "5edbd7d182af1f5aceab62bc",
            "donatorName": "Brian",
            "donationValue": 5000000
        }
    ],

"currentValue" : 1000000
```

I get my currentValue from donationValue sum in donator array :

```
donator.reduce((a, { donationValue }) => a + donationValue,0);
```

and I want to update the document by adding new object in *donator* array, and automatically updates *currentValue* field when the data updated.

I tried using aggregate

```
MyCollection.findByIdAndUpdate(id, [
      {
        $set: req.body,
        $set: { currentValue: { $sum: { $sum: donator.donationValue } } },
      },
    ]);
```

Comment: You are using update with aggregation pipeline. I guess you are using MongoDB v4.2?

Comment: Yes, i'm using MongoDB v.4.2

Answer (score 0):

It's a good practice to sanitise your input and not directly use `req.body`.

so let's say

```
const donator = sanitizeDonator(req.body)
```

Then you can add `donator` and update `currentValue` as follows.

Note that `_id` on donator won't be auto generated by the update query, so it has to be present in the `donator` object.

```
MyCollection.findByIdAndUpdate(id, [
  {
    $set: {
      donator: {
        $concatArrays: ["$donator", [donator]] // adding donator to the last element
      }
    }
  }, {
    $set: {
      currentValue: {
        $reduce: {
          initialValue: 0,
          input: "$donator",
          in: {
            $add: ["$$this.donationValue", "$$value"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

Relevant APIs
[`$concatArrays`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/),
[`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/)

Comment: thanks, the $concatArrays is what i need, but there's a problem with $reduce
i can't get the value of $$this.donationValue or $donator.donationValue, it always returns null, i tried it works with array of numbers but not array of objects

Comment: It should work, check if you have the property name correctly, does `.donationValue` exists in all your subdocument? Check out the [playground](https://play.db-ai.co/m/Xty8pQbYvgABFWHG)

Comment: In case the field name `donationValue` is correct, but it doesn't exist on all objects in `donator` array, you can wrap it with `$ifNull` like this `{ $ifNull: ["$$this.donationValue", 0] }` instead of just `"$$this.donationValue"`